# Use pandas df column as legend label?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

When plotting a pandas Datafarme column is it possible to use the Dataframe column name as the legend label instead of explicitly specifying the label?

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [0, 2, 1, 3], 
                        'col2': [9,7,8,9]}, 
                        index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

f = plt.figure()
ax = f.subplots()
ax.plot(df['col1'], label='col1') # How to not explicitly specify label?
# ax.plot(df['col1']) # This does not produce a legend label
ax.legend()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the pandas plotting API:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df['col1'].plot(ax=ax)
ax.legend()
```

Comment: I think you need to add `plt.legend()`

Comment: @learner - `ax.legend()`, which OP already has.